# Small Linq expression doesnt work

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have the short query below, which does not work.

What I'm trying to achieve is that only the occurences where departmentResources.IsHardware == true are going to be part of the "roomToAdd" I know the first part works fine, so its only the second part Im not sure about. (&& departmentResources.Contains(a.IsHardWare))"

```
IEnumerable<Resource> roomToAdd = taskResources
                    .Where(a => !departmentResources.Contains(a)&& departmentResources.Contains(a.IsHardWare));
```

Can any of you brilliant people out there give me a hint?

Comment: And departmentResources is what in this context (List(of),Array,ArrayList(of),...)?

Comment: Ah sorry, DepartmentResource is declared like this:   List<Resource> departmentResources;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try simply:

```
.Where(a => !departmentResources.Contains(a) && a.IsHardWare);
```

This says all the taskResources that are NOT in departmentResources and taskResources.IsHardWare is true.

Is that what you're after?

Comment: Hmm yes that is what I'm after, but I already tried that, and that did not work.. I might have to do some further investigation then.. I really thought I just couldn't get that expression to work.

Comment: @JesperPlantener Is the column `IsHardWare` a bool? If its not it might need to be `IsHardWare == "True" or whatever the string value is. (look out for case sensitivity)

Comment: @JesperPlantener Then your `Contains` is a problem.  If you are comparing different lists of objects, then the compare would be by reference, not value.  If they were not exactly the same object, it would fail.

Comment: Without the && ishardware, the expression returns 2 objects. With the expression it does not return any.. Im trying to only make it return 1 of the objects..

Comment: And you've debugged this and the IsHardWare value of one of them is true?

Comment: DOH! I just figured out what the problem is! If i'm not recreating the whole testcase before doing the debugging again, the object i'm looking for is gone.. So actually what you said in the first place, and what I tried first has been the correct answer the whole time.. Anyway thanks for your time!

Comment: @JesperPlantener Glad you got it solved and that I could help